# Returning a list of lists to the flow returns error saying list out of bounds

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I am returning a list of lists from Apex Invocable Method like below

Here is my Apex defined class which I am using it later to create an Apex defined object inside of the flow. This class is in its own file.

```
    public with sharing class CustomerAccountContactDto {
        public CustomerAccountContactDto() {
            //set defaults
            this.errorOcurred = false;
            this.passwordChangeIsRequired = false;
            this.passwordIsSet = false;
        }
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String contactName;
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String contactRoleType;
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public Boolean errorOcurred;
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=false)
        public Boolean passwordChangeIsRequired;
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=false)
        public Boolean passwordIsSet;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(
        Label='getPINPassword'
        Description='get PIN or Password Authentication Result by Account number and Object Id'
    )
    public static List<List<CustomerAccountContactDto>> getPassword(List<Request> requestList) {
            CustomerAccountContactDto response = new CustomerAccountContactDto();
            CustomerAccountContactDto response1 = new CustomerAccountContactDto();
response.contactName = 'First Record Name';
response.passwordChangeIsRequired = false;
response.passwordIsSet = true;
            
response1.contactName = 'Second Record Name';
response1.passwordChangeIsRequired = false;
response1.passwordIsSet = true;
            
        List<List<CustomerAccountContactDto>> responseWrapper = new List<List<CustomerAccountContactDto>>();
                System.debug('Response -'+response);
                System.debug('Response -'+response1);
                responseWrapper[0].add(response);
                responseWrapper[1].add(response1);
                return responseWrapper;
    }
```

The debug statements do print out the expected values from response and response1.

I created an Apex defined data type in the flow like below which references the above created CustomerAccountContactDto class and after I use this variable as an output variable for the apex action
[image]

[image]

And finally when I run the flow just after passing the ape action node it shows the below error-

```
 An Apex error occurred: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0
```

Comment: There's not enough code here for us to help you. Context is often important. I'd rather see too much code, which we can then trim down, than not enough, where we have to guess/make assumptions what you did.

Comment: We need to understand what `response` and `response1` are, the size of the input parameter list (the size of the output list must match the size of the input list) and just how you want to structure that `responseWrapper`.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have added more details, let me know if it is good

Comment: @PhilW I have added more details, let me know if it is good

Comment: Are you expecting to return a pair of "responses" for each `Request`?

Comment: Flows include automated bulkification of invocable methods. That's why you receive and return lists. You must process every input instance and provide an output per input.

Comment: This is just dummy data I created for testing. It won't be a pair of responses, it will be multiple records returned from an API call. Each record does not have any link to other records. I have added code on how each response is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with not populating the list in the correct way.

I created two new lists -

```
List<List<CustomerAccountContactDto>> customerAccountcontacts = new List<List<CustomerAccountContactDto>>();
List<CustomerAccountContactDto> contacts = new List<CustomerAccountContactDto>();
```

Then I populated the contacts list with the responses and finally added the contacts list to the customerAccountcontacts list.

```
response.contactName = 'First Record Name';
response.passwordChangeIsRequired = false;
response.passwordIsSet = true;
contacts.add(response);         
response1.contactName = 'Second Record Name';
response1.passwordChangeIsRequired = false;
response1.passwordIsSet = true;
contacts.add(response1);

customerAccountcontacts.add(contacts);
```

This way the flow is no more showing the out of bounds error.

Comment: This code still doesn't conform to flow requirements; if the flow provides *n* Request records in the parameters you must return *n* lists.

Comment: It is one list of lists that I am returning to the flow. I was able to retrieve multiple records inside of a screen component. The records are returned as part of an api call.

Comment: Read up on invocable methods. Flows can and do bulkify calls to your method when multiple executions of your flow are running in parallel. You can therefore get multiple requests. And then you HAVE to return a value per request (where here a value is a list) and these must be in the same order as the related requests.

Comment: Okay sure. Will look into it..

Comment: see also [related question/answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393238/how-to-parse-list-of-custom-apex-types-returned-from-invocablemethod-in-flow)